# Logstash cannot start because of multiple instances even though there are no instances of it running

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, logstash-configuration

I keep getting this error `[2019-02-26T16:50:41,329][FATAL][logstash.runner          ] Logstash could not be started because there is already another instance using the configured data directory.  If you wish to run multiple instances, you must change the "path.data" setting.`
 when I launch logstash. I am using the cli to launch logstash. The command that I execute is:

`screen -d -S logstash -m bash -c "cd;export JAVA_HOME=/nastools/jdk1.8.0_77/;  export LS_JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true; ~/monitoring/6.2.3/bin/logstash-6.2.3/bin/logstash -f ~/monitoring/6.2.3/config/logstash_forwarder/forwarder.conf"`

I don't have any instance of logstash running. I tried running this:
`ps xt | grep "logstash"` and it didn't return any process. I tried the following as well: `killall logstash` but to no avail, it gives me the same error. I tried restarting my machine as well but still the same error.

Has anyone experienced something similar? Kibana and elastic search launch just fine.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: In your pipelines.yml  you only have 1 pipeline?

Comment: My pipelines.yml is commented.

Comment: From the logstash logs: `Ignoring the 'pipelines.yml' file because modules or command line options are specified`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is solved now. I had to empty the contents of the data directory of logstash. I then restarted it and it generated the uuid and other files it needed.

Comment: how you do this? can you please tell me?

Answer (score 6):

To be more specific, you need to cd to the data folder of logstash (usually it is /usr/share/logstash/data) and delete the **.lock** file.

You can see if this file exists with:

```
ll -lah
```

In the data folder.
Learn it from http://www.programmersought.com/article/2009814657/;jsessionid=282FF6001AFE90D7D8609975B8222CE8

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo /usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash --path.settings /etc/logstash/ --path.data sensor39 -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/company_dump.conf --config.reload.automatic
```

Try this cmd I hope it will work(but please check the `.conf` file path)